# Finding required maximum current rating for a diode which will run in PWM mode

Tags: current, diodes, pwm, datasheet, specifications

Consider a diode rectifier which will transfer a PWM signal. The duty cycle rate of this PWM signal is \$D\$ (\$0 \le D \le 1\$). The diode on state current is \$I_{ON}\$, and no current will be drawn when the PWM is low (resistive load). And the datasheet says that the maximum continuous forward current of the diode is (\$I_{FM}\$).

How do I determine \$I_{FM}\$ (i.e.; choose a diode) from given \$D\$ and \$I_{ON}\$ values? Can we always assume that \$I_{FM} = D \times I_{ON}\$ for all duty cycle rates and PWM frequencies?

Please list other circuit specifications needed for making this calculation, if there is any.

Comment: Generally speaking the diode will have to be able to carry maximum DC amps to the load, plus the peak value of any AC current ripple. The peak ripple depends on the circuit, but thats where you would use duty cycle as a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at a typical switching diode [datasheet](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/1N/1N914.pdf), we have:

[image]

So, we should stay within the average forward current < 200mA **and** peak current < 400mA. 
Those limitations apply at 25°C, with derating above that.

So this particular diode will allow  \$I_{ON} \le \frac {I_{FM}}{D}\$ or 400mA (whichever is smaller) at 25°C, with linear derating above that to 50% at 100°C (see datasheet).

It's possible, however, that this is a homework problem in which your instructor wishes you to use an RMS value of the PWM waveform, in which case you should calculate the RMS current rather than the average current.

Answer (score 2):

> Can we always assume that \$I_{FM} = D \times I_{ON}\$ for all duty
>   cycle rates and PWM frequencies?

No, that would be naive. Assume duty cycle is virtually one, you wouldn't choose a diode with a continuous forward current maximum close to the working current. That would be asking for trouble - you need to de-rate appropriately, probably to about two-thirds (off-the-cuff rule of thumb). Diodes tend to be high failure devices, especially in power rectification and if you were familiar with [MIL-HDBK-217F](http://snebulos.mit.edu/projects/reference/MIL-STD/MIL-HDBK-217F-Notice2.pdf)\$^1\$ you'd probably derate more to give a useful life from the device.

If the duty cycle were low then you will get to a point where you can reasonably rely on the peak current handling ability of the diode.

---

\$^1\$ this document is still very useful despite its age and predicts the reliability of components based on application and ratings.